# Spring Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW nullfies autowired repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have a simple controller method, which is using `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` feature of Spring transaction.

```
@Autowired
GzrelimRepository gzrelimRepository;



@Autowired
RelimService relimService;

@RequestMapping("/startScanning")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void scanResults(@NotNull String matchingSrc, @NotNull String rangeStart, @NotNull String rangeEnd, @NotNull Integer scanPid){

    gzrelimRepository.pScanDupPidmWrap(matchingSrc, rangeStart, rangeEnd, scanPid);

}
```

When I invoke this method, the gzrelimRepository is null and I get null pointer exception error.

If I remove requires_new from propagation, things work.

The reason to use requires_new is that, scanning takes lot of time and I want to start scanning in its own independent new transaction and rest other things in normal existing transaction.

Is my approach correct? Should I try some other approach?

Comment: Setting an attribute of the `@Transactional` will not change how Spring creates and autowires your beans, so if `relimService` is null, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: its not the relimService  is null. its complaining about  
  gzrelimRepository; being null

Comment: Show full stacktrace.

Comment: I agreed with Andreas, the problem is elsewhere,, please provide some stack trace and other code you think that it's needed to show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you did NOT inject the `gzrelimRepository` bean to your controller.

```
@Autowired
RelimService relimService;

@Autowired
GzrelimRepository gzrelimRepository;

@RequestMapping("/startScanning")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void scanResults(@NotNull String matchingSrc, @NotNull String rangeStart, @NotNull String rangeEnd, @NotNull Integer scanPid){

    gzrelimRepository.pScanDupPidmWrap(matchingSrc, rangeStart, rangeEnd, scanPid);

}
```

**I recommend NOT to use `@Transactional` at the Controller level, rather the transactions need to be managed at the service/DAO layers.**

Comment: How do you know OP didn't autowire `gzrelimRepository`. OP didn't show the declaration, so how do you know whether it is autowired or not?

Comment: gzrelimRepository is null and I get null pointer exception error.

Comment: And OP continues "if I remove requires_new from propogation. things work.". So if removing `REQUIRES_NEW` will allow the code to run, how do you believe that with your assumption that `gzrelimRepository` is not `@Autowired`, the code would suddenly have a non-null value?

Comment: gzrelimRepository  is autowired.. 
Please see the code I have pasted here...It was missed..sorry about that..

Comment: @javaguy The premise of your answer is that `gzrelimRepository` was not autowired, which was an assumption based on undisplayed code. But if the code truly fails with NPE when propagation is `REQUIRES_NEW`, and works without error when `REQUIRES_NEW` is removed and nothing else is changed, then your premise cannot be correct. If your premise had been correct, it would fail with NPE in both cases.